# In a vector of pairs, find pair that has first value equal to X and return second value, or return Y

Tags: c++

I have a vector of pairs such as

```
std::vector< std::pair <int, double> > vec = { {1, 2.0}, {5, 21.0} };
```

I would like to check whether this vector has a pair in which the first element is equal to, say 5. If this is the case, then I would like to return the second element of that pair, 21.0. If not, then return, say, 99.9.

I know I can use `std:find` and family, but not sure how to do the returning value part. For example, searching through stackoverflow, below seems like an approximate solution:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

double MyFunc(int key) const {
    if (std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&key](std::pair<int, double> const& elem) {
                                           return elem.first == key;
                                           }))
           return ???;
    else
           return 99.9;
}
```

Is this a possible solution? What should I fill `???;` with? As you can see, I'm not an experienced programmer in C++ and the likes, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
    [&key](const std::pair<int, double>& elem) {
        return elem.first == key;
    });
return it != vec.end() ? it->second : 99.9;
```

Comment: Isn't this returning the first element?

Comment: @cosmia1 It will return an iterator to the pair who has the first element as key.

Comment: @ThePhilomath so I could write vec[it].second to extract the second element? The compact notation is a little tricky for me. How can I return the second element instead of the iterator?

Comment: @cosmia1 : you can't return anything except an `inputIterator` from find_if. What you can do is take a local variable in your function and capture it in lambda and set it if `elem.first == key`

Comment: To extract the second element using an iterator just write `it->second`

Comment: @cosmia1   - `it` is an iterator, not an index of an element.   Since elements of the vector are a `std::pair<int, double>`, the second element of the pair sought is `it->second`.     Read up on iterators.   Don't make the mistake of letting your lack of understanding lead you to disregard a correct solution.

Comment: just an fyi, i didn't downvote this answer. i'll try to work this out.